# Failed to retrieve static char * array

Tags: c++

I have following code snippet, intention is to get certain item list and print. It is compiling fine but at run time , outputs are not as expected. I have added comments where result is unexpected. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class cSample
{
private:
    static const char *list1[];
    static const char *list2[];

public:
    cSample();
    const char **GetList(int);
};

cSample::cSample()
{
}

const char *cSample::list1[] = {"Item1" , "Item2" , "Item3"};
const char *cSample::list2[] = {"Item4" ,"Item5" ,"Item6"};

const char **cSample::GetList(int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
    case 1:
        return cSample::list1;
        break;
    case 2:
        return cSample::list2;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc , const char *argv[])
{
    cSample *oSample = new cSample();

    const char**list1Item = oSample->GetList(1);//Here getlist returns list1+list2 item which is wrong , I am not sure why...
    cout << "Items from List1 " << endl; 
    while(*list1Item != NULL)
    {
        cout << *list1Item << endl;
        list1Item++;
    }

    const char **list2Item = oSample->GetList(2);//whereas list2 items are returned correctly using same method any idea why?
    cout << "Items from list2" << endl;
    while(*list2Item != NULL)
    {
        cout << *list2Item << endl;
        list2Item++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a NULL to terminate your lists

```
const char *cSample::list1[] = {"Item1" , "Item2" , "Item3", NULL};
```

Comment: Should also add a `NULL` to `list2[]` or else it is UB.

Comment: You may prefer `nullptr` since C++11.

Answer (score 1):

You have never set the last element of your list array to `NULL`, and you keep incrementing `list1Item`. Actually, what you are doing is [UB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Just add a `NULL`, to avoid the behavior you are experiencing, like,

```
const char *cSample::list1[] = {"Item1" , "Item2" , "Item3", 0};
const char *cSample::list2[] = {"Item4" ,"Item5" ,"Item6", 0};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting your arrays to be null-terminated, but they're not. So when you enumerate `list1` you run straight off the end and into `list2`.

Answer (score 0):

Like others already mentioned, you need to null terminate your lists

> ```
> #include <iostream>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> class cSample
> {
> private:
>     static const char *list1[];
>     static const char *list2[];
>
> public:
>     cSample();
>     const char **GetList(int);
> };
>
> cSample::cSample()
> {
> }
>
> const char *cSample::list1[] = {"Item1" , "Item2" , "Item3", '\0'};
> const char *cSample::list2[] = {"Item4" ,"Item5" ,"Item6", '\0'};
>
> const char **cSample::GetList(int i)
> {
>     switch(i)
>     {
>     case 1:
>         return cSample::list1;
>         break;
>     case 2:
>         return cSample::list2;
>         break;
>     default:
>         break;
>     }
> }
>
> int main(int argc , const char *argv[])
> {
>     cSample *oSample = new cSample();
>
>     const char **list1Item = oSample->GetList(1);//Here getlist returns list1+list2 item which is wrong , I am not sure why...
>     cout << "Items from List1 " << endl; 
>     while(*list1Item != NULL)
>     {
>         cout << *list1Item << endl;
>         list1Item++;
>     }
>
>     const char **list2Item = oSample->GetList(2);//whereas list2 items are returned correctly using same method any idea why?
>     cout << "Items from list2" << endl;
>     while(*list2Item != NULL)
>     {
>         cout << *list2Item << endl;
>         list2Item++;
>     }
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: Whereas `nullptr` is prefered to `NULL`, here your zero value `\0` is not of the correct type :-/.

Comment: a null pointer that internally is represented as 0xDEADBEEF is still a null pointer, no matter what its bitstring looks like, and it will still compare equal to NULL, 0, \0 and all other null pointer constant forms.

Comment: I don't say your answer is incorrect, just that it is misleading, why  using **char** `\0` instead of the correct type ?